# Need regex to strip away remaing part of a path

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex which will strip away the rest of the path after a particular folder name.

**If Input is:**

```
/Repository/Framework/PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6/core/src/Pita.x86.Interfaces/IDemoReader.cs
```

**Output should be:**

```
/Repository/Framework/PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6
```

**Some constrains:** 
`ChangePack-` will be followed change pack id which is a mix of numbers or alphabets a-z or A-Z only in any order. And there is no limit on length of change pack id.
`ChangePack-` is a constant. It will always be there.

And the text before the ChangePack can also change. Like it can also be:

```
/Repository/Demo1/Demo2/4.3//PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6/core/src/Pita.x86.Interfaces
```

My regex-fu is bad. What I have come up with till now is:

```
^(.*?)\-6a7B6
```

I need to make this generic.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regex can do the trick.

```
^(.*?ChangePack-[\w]+)
```

Input:

```
/Repository/Framework/PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6/core/src/Pita.x86.Interfaces/IDemoReader.cs
/Repository/Demo1/Demo2/4.3//PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6/core/src/Pita.x86.Interfaces
```

Output:

```
/Repository/Framework/PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6
/Repository/Demo1/Demo2/4.3//PITA/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6
```

Check out the live [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eI6pE3/1).

Comment: What if your input is `/Repository/Framework/ChangePack-7/branches/ChangePack-6a7B6/hh1`?

Comment: @NotAgain this will also accept `/Repository/Framework/ChangePack-7/branches/ChangePack-6a_7B6`

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*?ChangePack-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Try this.Instead of replace grab the match `$1` or `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/17

Answer (score 0):

Will you always have '/Repository/Framework/PITA/branches/' at the beginning? If so, this will do the trick:

```
/Repository/Framework/PITA/branches/\w+-\w*
```

Comment: No. It can change. The code can be checked out from any point in the SVN to create a change pack. The path then changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you could can use `split` and `join` functions. Example python:

```
path = "/a/b/c/d/e"
folders = path.split("/")
newpath = "/".join(folders[:3]) #trims off everything from the third folder over
print(newpath) #prints "/a/b"
```

If you really want regex, try something like `^.*\/folder\/` where `folder` is the name of the directory you want to match.

Comment: I will be working in windows batch file environment. So split and join might be a bit difficult. But bigger issue is that it will not be third folder always. Its position changes.

Comment: If you really want regex, try something like `^.*\/folder\/`. It will match from the beginning up to and through the first instance of `folder`